# I need to remove navigation bar instead of hiding it

Tags: android

I understand that it's a bad practice for android app, but somehow I really need to enforce user complete the action and not allow to use any navigation bar at that moment, I found some solution which is just hiding it or override the function, but what I need is totally disable it and prevent it from showing out.

I have tried something like this, this is already close to what I want to do but I need to prevent the navigation bar from showing out again.

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
  View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
  decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
               | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
               | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
               | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
               | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
               | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Is there any solution for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

After I did some research about my action, I found out there's research mentioning that "**Android treats such behavior as malware. Android is designed to keep control of the device in the hands of the user and tries very hard to prevent apps from stealing that control."** For people who trying to writing lock screen app, parental control app or kiosk app. **Just don't do that no matter how strong is your reason**. For kiosk app, just find an alternate way to achieve what are you trying to do.